# How to include ALL attributes when using DocBin() or doc.to_array() methods in spaCy?

Tags: python, arrays, serialization, attributes, spacy

I simply need to add all attributes instead of adding them one by one in [DocBin() method](https://spacy.io/api/docbin#init) in spaCy (version 2.2)

So instead of this:

```py
import spacy # V2.2
from spacy.tokens import DocBin # V2.2

doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=["LEMMA", "ENT_IOB", "ENT_TYPE"])
```

I want to do something like:

```py
doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=all) # which doesn't work
```

To include every single available attribute.

What's the solution?

Comment: Anyone can help me with this question?

Comment: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/5411 You need to create a list manually or hunt something in the code, I found this, but its incomplete (ORTH missing): https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/0061992d958ca56b2e5ba1ebd1fadee402fd65d7/spacy/lang/lex_attrs.py or https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/0061992d958ca56b2e5ba1ebd1fadee402fd65d7/spacy/attrs.pyx

Answer (score 0):

all docbin attributes can be found [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/tokens/doc.pyx), try:

```
from spacy.tokens.doc import DOCBIN_ALL_ATTRS as all_attrs
doc_bin = DocBin(attrs=all_attrs)
```